# Python erasing ini files

Tags: python

So I write a .ini file and then some code in python, python interacts with the ini file (in this case reads it) and spits out [] when I print the result. When I go back into the ini file everything is gone, am I doing something wrong?

```
import configparser

cfg = configparser.ConfigParser()

f = open('Config.ini', 'w')
print(cfg.read('CYPHER'))
f.close()
```

That's my code, and I am utterly confused.

Answer (score 1):

`open('Config.ini', 'w')` deletes the file. See [Python docs on `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), which says:

> open for writing, truncating the file first

Instead of that, open the file in reading mode: `open('Config.ini', 'r')`, or better yet, for reading as a textual file: `open('Config.ini', 'rt')`.